# Dependency Injection in C# RabbitMQ EventHandler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, rabbitmq

RabbitMQ exposes a `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer.Received` EventHandler on message received.

Since this is a top level Event no Dependency Injection is available unless a specific scope is created for it and passed as an enclosing variable.

```
#pragma warning disable CA2000 // Dispose objects before losing scope
var serviceScope = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope();
#pragma warning restore CA2000 // Dispose objects before losing scope

consumer.Received += async (object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs eventArgs) => 
{
    try 
    {
         // Do something
    }
    finally
    {
        scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do DI with top level events like this one?

Comment: When you say "a better way" the question is "better than what?" What are you trying to do here, and why do you need to inject a dependency at this particular location?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a known pattern to do use an injected service inside of my event handler. This solution sounds to me more like a "hack" than a real way to inject services into my event handler. However, creating a new composite root as suggested already inside of my event handler is not trivial. I haven't figured out yet how to do it.

Comment: The reason to use DI is to support testability of your code. It is difficult or impossible to test anonymous functions. Thus, DI has no legitimate purpose here. This is why I'm trying to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that runs as part of the `Received` handler can be considered to be part of your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). This is the place where you would start a new DI scope and resolve your service from that scope and invoke that service.

This is similar to how you would apply DI for operations that are triggered based on a timer. [Section 8.3.3](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-8/196) of my book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl) contains an example of this:

```cs
// Listing 8.14
public static class Program
{
    private static Composer composer;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var money = new Money(    
            currency: new Currency(code: args[0]),    
            amount: decimal.Parse(args[1]));    

        composer = new Composer(LoadConnectionString());

        var timer = new Timer(interval: 60000);    
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => DisplayRates(money);  
        timer.Start();    

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();    
    }

    private static void DisplayRates(Money money)
    {
        CurrencyRateDisplayer displayer =
            composer.CreateRateDisplayer();    

        displayer.DisplayRatesFor(money);
    }

    private static string LoadConnectionString() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely confirms I need to re create a Composition Root. The problem is I need to do it in a lower layer of the code, and would need to figure out how to re create one with all original services. Is there maybe a clever way to do it with .NET DI extensions or do I need to redefine all services?

Comment: In case you can't make the `consumer.Received +=` part of the startup path of your application, the solution is to use abstractions. Let the `consumer.Received +=` handler depend on the abstraction and let the Composition Root provide the right implementation that allows creating message handlers and invoking them with the message.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I need to figure out how to make the handler depend on the abstraction. Not sure if I can DI an event handler directly but I will try that or some other way. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting to see that you are using RabbitMQ directly, instead of using a framework such as MassTransit or NServiceBus. They provide great flexibility and features out of the box (such as auto reconnect, retry, DI, etc) that you'd otherwise would have to build and maintain by hand.

Comment: Didn't know about them. Will definitely give them a look ;) Thanks